# how to scrape a page which uses if-non-match and cookies with scrapy or any other tool?

Tags: caching, web-scraping, scrapy, if-none-match

I am trying to scrape an API that returns a JSON object but it only returns a JSON very first time and after it, it's not returning anything. i am using "if-none-match" header with Cookies but i want to do it without Cookies because I have lots of API of this category to scrape.

Here is my spider code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Spider, Request
import json
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

header_data = {'authority': 'shopee.com.my',
    'method': 'GET',
    'scheme': 'https',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'if-none-match-': '*',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'x-shopee-language': 'en',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    }


class TestSales(Spider):
    name = "testsales"
    allowed_domains = ['shopee.com', 'shopee.com.my', 'shopee.com.my/api/']
    cookie_string = {'SPC_U':'-', 'SPC_IA':'-1' , 'SPC_EC':'-' , 'SPC_F':'7jrWAm4XYNNtyVAk83GPknN8NbCMQEIk', 'REC_T_ID':'476673f8-eeb0-11ea-8919-48df374df85c', '_gcl_au':'1.1.1197882328.1599225148', '_med':'refer', '_fbp':'fb.2.1599225150134.114138691', 'language':'en', '_ga':'GA1.3.1167355736.1599225151', 'SPC_SI':'mall.gTmrpiDl24JHLSNwnCw107mao3hd8qGP', 'csrftoken':'2ntG40uuWzOLUsjv5Sn8glBUQjXtbGgo', 'welcomePkgShown':'true', '_gid':'GA1.3.590966412.1602427202', 'AMP_TOKEN':'%24NOT_FOUND', 'SPC_CT_21c6f4cb':'1602508637.vtyz9yfI6ckMZBdT9dlICuAYf7crlEQ6NwQScaB2VXI=', 'SPC_CT_087ee755':'1602508652.ihdXyWUp3wFdBN1FGrKejd91MM8sJHEYCPqcgmKqpdA=', '_dc_gtm_UA-61915055-6':'1', 'SPC_R_T_ID':'vT4Yxil96kYSRG2GIhtzk8fRJldlPJ1/szTbz9sG21nTJr4zDoOnnxFEgYe2Ea+RhM0H8q0m/SFWBMO7ktpU5Kim0CJneelIboFavxAVwb0=', 'SPC_T_IV':'hhHcCbIpVvuchn7SbLYeFw==', 'SPC_R_T_IV':'hhHcCbIpVvuchn7SbLYeFw==', 'SPC_T_ID':'vT4Yxil96kYSRG2GIhtzk8fRJldlPJ1/szTbz9sG21nTJr4zDoOnnxFEgYe2Ea+RhM0H8q0m/SFWBMO7ktpU5Kim0CJneelIboFavxAVwb0='}

    custom_settings = {
        'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED' : 'True',
        # The initial download delay
        'AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY' : '0.5',
        # The maximum download delay to be set in case of high latencies
        'AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY' : '10',
        # The average number of requests Scrapy should be sending in parallel to
        # each remote server
        'AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY' : '1.0',
        # 'DNSCACHE_ENABLED' : 'False',
        # 'COOKIES_ENABLED': 'False',
    }
            
        

    def start_requests(self):
        subcat_url = '/Baby-Toddler-Play-cat.27.23785'
        id = subcat_url.split('.')[-1]
        header_data['path'] = f'/api/v2/search_items/?by=sales&limit=50&match_id={id}&newest=0&order=desc&page_type=search&version=2'
        header_data['referer'] = f'https://shopee.com.my{subcat_url}?page=0&sortBy=sales'
        url = f'https://shopee.com.my/api/v2/search_items/?by=sales&limit=50&match_id={id}&newest=0&order=desc&page_type=search&version=2'

        yield Request(url=url, headers=header_data, #cookies=self.cookie_string,
                        cb_kwargs={'subcat': 'baby tobbler play cat', 'category': 'baby and toys' })



    def parse(self, response, subcat, category):
        # pass
        try:
            jdata = json.loads(response.body)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'exception: {e}')
            print(response.body)
            return None

        items = jdata['items']

        for item in items:
            name = item['name']
            image_path = item['image']
            absolute_image = f'https://cf.shopee.com.my/file/{image_path}_tn'
            print(f'this is  absolute image {absolute_image}')
            subcategory = subcat
            monthly_sold = 'pending'
            price = float(item['price'])/100000
            total_sold = item['sold']
            location = item['shop_location']
            stock = item['stock']

            print(name)
            print(price)
            print(total_sold)
            print(location)
            print(stock)


app = CrawlerProcess()
app.crawl(TestSales)
app.start()
```

This is the page url which you can see the entering on browser: https://shopee.com.my/Baby-Toddler-Play-cat.27.23785?page=0&sortBy=sales

This is the API url which you can also find from developers tool of that page: https://shopee.com.my/api/v2/search_items/?by=sales&limit=50&match_id=23785&newest=0&order=desc&page_type=search&version=2

Please tell me how to handle 'cache' or 'if-none-match' because i can't understand how to handle it.
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

All you need to generate API GET requests is category identificator which is **match_id** and start item number which is **newest** parameter.

Using link template *[https://shopee.com.my/api/v2/search_items/?by=sales&limit=50&match_id={category_id}&newest={start_item_number}&order=desc&page_type=search&version=2](https://shopee.com.my/api/v2/search_items/?by=sales&limit=50&match_id=%7Bcategory_id%7D&newest=%7Bstart_item_number%7D&order=desc&page_type=search&version=2)* you can fetch any API category endpoint.

There's no need to manage cookies or even headers in this case. API is not restrictive at all.

**UPDATE:**

This worked for me in scrapy shell:

```
from scrapy import Request

url = 'https://shopee.com.my/api/v2/search_items/?by=sales&limit=50&match_id=23785&newest=50&order=desc&page_type=search&version=2'

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
}


request = Request(
    url=url,
    method='GET',
    dont_filter=True,
    headers=headers,
)

fetch(request)
```

Comment: sorry to say but you cannot fetch shopee's any api without attaching headers to it. i have tried a lot of things and nothing works.

Comment: my bad. I was running spider inside of the project with automatic headers insertion.
Updated my answer.

Comment: not all the api's are catching from this type of method. can you please try it with this url: https://shopee.com.my/api/v2/search_items/?by=sales&limit=50&match_id=2299&newest=0&order=desc&page_type=search&version=2